# What are the legal ramifications of the Houthi attacks in the Red Sea?

Tags: international-law, houthi-movement

I am curious about the legal aspects of the Houthi attacks in the Red Sea. On the one hand, the attacks may seem to be unprovoked belligerent actions disrupting global trade and endangering the lives of civilian seafarers. On the other hand, a counterargument may be that, in light of the determination by the ICJ that Israel is plausibly committing genocide in Gaza, the Houthi actions are a just humanitarian intervention to prevent the crime of genocide and an instance of the ["responsibility to protect".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_to_protect)

The attacks thus seem in a legally murky territory similar to the NATO bombing in Yugoslavia.

> What are arguments for and against its legality? Is there a legal consensus?

Comment: The "on the other hand" argument is quite a stretch. Attacks on trade ships can't do anything in relation to Israel or Gaza

Comment: This seems a lot like a push question. As Ccm points out, your 'the other hand' argument (attacking unrelated civilian targets to prevent alleged genocide or even civilian suffering more generally) doesn't make much sense. Besides, you misrepresent the ICJ ruling which does not say that "Israel is plausibly committing genocide". The court has [not ruled on that yet](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/world-court-rule-urgent-measures-gaza-genocide-case-2024-01-26/). (edit: they did not definitively rule on that)

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better placed at law.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have difficulty finding Western legal scholars defending the Houthis. And probably even Russian or Chinese ones (see below).

To start though, I have to say I disagree with the other answer the Houthis' attacks have been totally indiscriminate. They do seem to try to avoid hitting any Russian or Chinese ships... and been succeeding in that regard to some extent, even [according](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-68159939) to the Western press. Although with their limited intel, they did make some mistakes in that regard.

> In total, 28 vessels have been targeted since Houthi attacks began in November. We've identified seven of these with links to Israeli companies, individuals or destinations.
>
> BBC Verify has used vessel tracking data and official company records to establish these ownership links where possible. However, identifying vessel affiliation is not a straightforward process as multiple layers of company ownership can be difficult to penetrate.
>
> Of the nine ships attacked since the air strikes began [on Jan 12], five had American or British links, and none had identifiable Israeli links. [...]
>
> Some Chinese companies have capitalised on assurances of safe passage by the Houthis, and **Lloyd's List Intelligence says that the proportion of Chinese-affiliated shipping has increased since the end of November from 13% to 28% of all vessels passing through the Red Sea**.

Also, *The Economist* [reports](https://www.economist.com/china/2024/02/01/is-china-a-winner-from-the-red-sea-attacks) a surge in China-related info in the Red Sea:

> Ships try to protect themselves from Houthi attacks by making clear a link with China in their automated identification systems—transponders that are fitted on ships above a certain tonnage on international voyages. By late January, more than 30 vessels per day in the Red Sea were advertising such a connection, Spire Global’s analysts found (see chart 2).
>
> [image]

The Houthis did attack a couple of tankers carrying Russian oil... by mistake. An explanation for that is [outdated info](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/houthis-mistakenly-target-tanker-carrying-russian-oil-ambrey-report-2024-01-12/) in international databases and Russia's moves over the last year to get a ["shadow fleet"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Azm4yKKIlqE). And a hit on Hong Kong ship was likewise [attributed](https://www.economist.com/china/2024/02/01/is-china-a-winner-from-the-red-sea-attacks) to outdated info (the ship had been previously chartered by an Israeli firm).

Anyhow, prior to the escalation that now declaratively involves US- & UK-merchant ships too, it's hard to say how well targeted the Houthi "sanctions" were, against Israeli-connected businesses. BBC's account of 7/28 means that Houthis' intel was mostly flawed in Israeli regards.

But with their sloppy intel also threatening Russian interests a bit, even Kremlin spokesman Peskov [criticized the Houthi attacks](https://tass.com/politics/1731551), and called them to stop.

> Peskov noted: "We have repeatedly called on the Houthis to abandon this practice because we believe it is extremely wrong."

... all while blasting the US & UK bombings as unauthorized (by the UNSC)--the January 10 UNSC resolution was a masterstroke of ambiguity, [according to China, at least](https://press.un.org/en/2024/sc15561.doc.htm). China's [own statement](https://time.com/6588884/china-urges-houthis-stop-red-sea-attacks/) on the attacks is slightly more interesting, as they only explicitly condemned the attacks on civilian ships:

> Chinese Foreign Ministry spokesman Wang Wenbin said Friday at a regular press briefing in Beijing [:] "We urge the cessation of attacks and harassment against civilian ships, and urge all parties to stop fueling the tensions."

Anyhow, no P5 power says that what the Houthis are doing is justified or proportionate. (Yeah, Russia and China have criticized the US & UK bombing response, to various degrees--Russia more explicitly than China--, but that's another matter.)

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, as noted in a comment from JJJ:

> the ICJ ruling which does not say that "Israel is plausibly committing
> genocide". The court has [not ruled on that yet](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/world-court-rule-urgent-measures-gaza-genocide-case-2024-01-26/).

There is no legitimate argument that "Houthi actions are a just humanitarian intervention to prevent the crime of genocide".

Their attacks do not have a meaningful nexus with anything going on in the current Gaza conflict outside their own self-delusions. Most of their attacks are on merchant ships have no connection to the conflict. The Houthis have indiscriminately attacked [commercial ships linked to 55 different countries](https://4/01/09/politics/us-navy-houthi-missiles-drones-red-sea/index.html), in the vast majority of cases having no link whatsoever to Israel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151279/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-einpoklum).

Comment: It turns out the court did rule on plausibility which is a specific requirement the ICJ uses for provisional measures, see [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/leiden-journal-of-international-law/article/abs/plausibility-in-the-provisional-measures-jurisprudence-of-the-international-court-of-justice/D84809A540DD8369900C6407CE197A3F).